# Cabling order on ProLiant DL180 G5 with SmartArray P800 and 3 x MSA 60 enclosures

Tags: raid, storage, hp-smart-array

For some reason I need to power up a system full of data without having any documentation about cabling.

I have :

- 1x Proliant DL 180 G5 with P800
- 3x full loaded smart array 60 with probably 2 logical drive full of data

The Proliant DL 180 can boot without any smart array 60 attached; the OS is on the internal HD.

My question, based on the fact that I'm not sure about the cabling schema (which array on which port, which array behind which one, ...) is can I lose data if I connect everything in the wrong order ?

Comment: You should be calling a HP partner and pay a consultant to help you out

Comment: I called and they told me they cannot help me because they have no proof the data are still on the array

Comment: Do you have any information on how things were connected before?

Comment: No... Server came from a bankrupted company bought by my customer. Server were un-racked and we cannot thrust anything in place, including tag on servers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't connect things in the wrong order. You won't necessarily lose data, but follow the instructions below before you power things on.

See the [HP MSA60 manual](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00807290/c00807290.pdf): Page 21 describes the setup you're talking about.

You're running a 1+2 cascaded configuration, so note the `IN` and `OUT` ports on the rear of the storage enclosure. The `IN` is the left port. `OUT` is the right port. The left connector of the I/O module is for input from the server. The right connector of the I/O module is for output to another storage enclosure.

So:

- DL180 G5 P800 (either port) to `IN` of MSA60 #1
- `OUT` of MSA60 #1 to `IN` of MSA60 #2
- `OUT` of MSA60 #2 to `IN` of MSA60 #3

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have read that document. My question is just that I have 3 array and two port on the server. If I connect array 1 & 2 on port 1 and array 3 on port 2 but that it was configured within an other order, for instance everything on port 2, will I loose data ?

Comment: No. They are cascaded. You're only going to use one of the ports on the server. The RAID configuration is on the disks, so the order does not matter.

Comment: @aligot If you've read that document before posting that comment, you need to stop and back away from the server hardware. Find someone who can read and comprehend directions, have them set this up. My apologies if that's blunt, but what you're saying implies that you can not follow directions.

Comment: @ChrisS I have read the manual, I did call HP twice... And at the end they told me they cannot answer whether or not they may be data loss if it is connect in wrong order... just to protect them selves. Even If I'm sure there is two devices on a port and one on the second I do not know which one of the three array is alone for instance. ewwhite seems to says the order does not matter which is just what I asking for :)